# Android Studio 3.0 Dependency issue

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, dependencies, android-studio-3.0

Getting Error:

> Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.googlecode.mp4parser:isoparser:1.1.22.
>       Open File
> Show Details

For Dependency:

```
compile 'com.googlecode.mp4parser:isoparser:1.1.22'
```

But for dependency:

```
compile 'com.googlecode.mp4parser:isoparser:1.1.20'
```

**Gradle Sync Successfully.**

Tried using repository:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Detailed Error:

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@StagingUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.googlecode.mp4parser:isoparser:1.1.22.

Could not resolve com.googlecode.mp4parser:isoparser:1.1.22.
Required by:
    project :app

> Could not resolve com.googlecode.mp4parser:isoparser:1.1.22.
>   Could not get resource 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/googlecode/mp4parser/isoparser/1.1.22/isoparser-1.1.22.pom'.
>   org.apache.http.ssl.SSLInitializationException: malformed input around byte 0
>   malformed input around byte 0
>   malformed input around byte 0

Comment: will appreciate if u could approve the answer...

Comment: Issue is with gradle *https://github.com/sannies/mp4parser/issues/95*, importing jar works fine, but i want to know exact issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lots of research and analysis, re-installing android studio 3.0 resolves issue.

Comment: Re-installing Android Studio 3.0 fixing the issue is consistent with the problem I discovered in my answer in this thread. I believe the issue can be fixed without needing a full reinstall by replacing AS's certificate authority store.

Answer (score 4):

Just make sure your root level `gradle.build` file is something like this. You need repo in both project and all project:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I was able to resolve dependency:

[image]

Comment: have u tried using **compile 'com.googlecode.mp4parser:isoparser:1.1.22'** in dependency. as i am still facing issue.

Comment: just posted the pic,

Comment: Omg check this link, https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.mp4parser/isoparser , The latest is 1.1.22 there is no such version 1.2.22 that exists, also check my image. U cannot find something that does not exists. can u now? OMG

Comment: Yes, i am using same. which i have posted in question.

Comment: SO it is resolving correctly, try clean build, Also try with Gradle wrapper 4.3-all.zip

Comment: change the grdlewrapper property file

Comment: all done, still facing issue, now i have imported jar module.

Comment: did u try the gradle wrapper change?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158043/discussion-between-tulsiram-rathod-and-niraj-sanghani).

Answer (score 4):

Just spent 1.5 hours investigating this. My root cause error was

```
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
Could not resolve io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+.
 Required by:
     project :
  > Could not resolve io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+.
     > Failed to list versions for io.fabric.tools:gradle.
        > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/fabric/tools/gradle/maven-metadata.xml.
           > org.apache.http.ssl.SSLInitializationException: malformed input around byte 12
```

In the `idea.log` file, I found this logtrace:

```
2018-02-15 18:32:32,220 [entQueue-0]  ERROR - net.ssl.ConfirmingTrustManager - Cannot get system trust store 
java.security.KeyStoreException: problem accessing trust storejava.io.UTFDataFormatException: malformed input around byte 12
    at sun.security.ssl.TrustManagerFactoryImpl.engineInit(TrustManagerFactoryImpl.java:74)

    at javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory.init(TrustManagerFactory.java:250)

    at com.intellij.util.net.ssl.ConfirmingTrustManager.getSystemDefault(ConfirmingTrustManager.java:82)

    at com.intellij.util.net.ssl.ConfirmingTrustManager.createForStorage(ConfirmingTrustManager.java:75)

    at com.intellij.util.net.ssl.CertificateManager.<init>(CertificateManager.java:130)
```

As it turns out the issue was not with Gradle at all, but with Android Studio's internal JRE runtime.

I got the same `malformed input around byte 12` error when running `keytool` against the cacerts file for the android studio JRE

```
> keytool.exe -list -keystore /c/Program\ Files/Android/Android\ Studio/jre/jre/lib/security/cacerts
keytool error: java.io.UTFDataFormatException: malformed input around byte 12
```

I replaced the `cacerts` file in my android studio install with the one from my machine's java install and things are back to normal. My assumption is that the file was corrupted during the update to 3.0, which seems to be the consistent thread in the people who have seen this.

Hope this helps anyone still experiencing this issue.

Comment: I got stuck on the on Mac OS (10.12.8). Thanks for sorting this!

Answer (score 0):

As I check `isoparser` artifact also available in [jcenter](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter/com.googlecode.mp4parser:isoparser) repo.

so add jcenter in your repository link.

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    google()        // <- required, when artifact is in google repo
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add also these repos:

```
jcenter()
google()
```

if you are behind proxy there may be problems with https connection so you may force it to use http, by adding:

```
maven { url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/" }
maven { url "http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2" }
maven { url "http://maven.google.com" }
```

UPDATE: Yesterday I faced the similar package error, tried everything but finally the only solution was deleting entire **.gradle** folder in user profile (not in project), or in user home directory in Linux. After that a long sync will start but finally everything will be ok.
It seems that this problem caused by gradle cache corrupted during AS update to the new release. It happen to me in both Windows and Fedora systems. And HTTP error message just set all people to seek the solutioin in the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that "Offline work" in "Settings" -> "Build, execution, deployment" -> "Gradle" is disabled.