# After updated to android studio my .apk file is generating in project\app\build\apk\debud\text.apk and cannot installing manually to other phones,why?

Tags: android, debugging, apk, adb, android-studio-3.0

APK installation shows error `app not installed`. This is happening for all APK files of project but running a complete project and installing the app in emulator works properly.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio 3.0 Dependency issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47068373/android-studio-3-0-dependency-issue)

Answer (score 0):

Try Cleaning and rebuild your project, then if this does not worked, try re-installing android studio 3.0 to resolve the issue.